# Mono for Android on OSX Lion : Error XA9010: Unable to determine license edition. (XA9010)

Tags: xamarin.android

I start to get this error since yesterday after updated my Mono for Android to 4.6.0-49.This happens on OSX Lion, does anyone have the same problem?

I am pretty sure that I have the correct license and I even tried to reactivate it but still doesn't work.

Comment: You should contact Xamarin Support at contact@xamarin.com so they can help you out.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? Please share how.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support from the Xamarin guys